# Про hover и opacity

Tags: css, hover, opacity

Такая ситуация:

```css
.menu {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.link {
  color: #000;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity: unset; // ясно, что не поможет
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Как видите из кода, мне нужен белый фон для меню, но при этом чуть прозрачный. Я ничего не нашел кроме `opacity`. И это меняет не только фон, но и ссылку внутри меню, и, кстати, это тоже мне вполне выгодно. Но вот при наведении мыши (`hover`) мне нужно, чтобы ссылка потеряла влияние `opacity` и стала абсолютно черной, но фон оставался прозрачным. Как быть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть формат цветов `RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` — в качестве 4-го параметра указывается прозрачность, также как и opacity - между 0 и 1.

В 16-ричном формате можно просто добавить 4-ю пару цифр. В виде `#ff000088` или, если все пары одинаковые, сократить до `#f008`. В итоге, можно менять прозрачность конкретного фона, а не всего элемента через opacity.

```css
.menu {
  background: #fff8; /* полупрозрачный белый #ffffff88 <> RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0.53)*/
}

.link {
  color: #0008; /* Полупрозрачный черный #00000088 <> RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.53)*/ 
}

.link:hover {
  color: #000; /* Обычный черный #000000 <> RGB(0, 0, 0) <> RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1)*/
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="link">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! вообще не знал про прозрачность в rgb,,, супер! .

Answer (score 3):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527049979667-990f1d0d8e7f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=633&q=80');
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
  list-style: none;
}

li {}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! В вашем коде обнаружил очень полезную для меня штучку, хоть о ней и не спросил))) круто!